# The github actions cache does not work for new PRs

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, caching, github-actions

I'm setting up CI for a Kotlin and Spring Boot project using GitHub Actions. Below is my GitHub Actions CI script:

```
name: backend_CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - dev
      - main
      - feature/**
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions: write-all

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Cache gradle packages
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*', '**/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'corretto'
          cache: gradle

      - name: Assign grant gradlew
        run: chmod +x gradlew

      - name: Test with gradle
        run: ./gradlew --info test
```

Every time the workflow runs, it downloads Gradle 8.5 and the project's external dependencies again, so I applied caching as seen above.

However, caching does not seem to work across different PRs. For instance, if I create a PR "A" and run the workflow, caching works for subsequent runs within the same PR. But when I create a new PR "B", it does not find the cache and downloads Gradle and external dependencies again.

How can I resolve this issue? The same problem occurs when using gradle/gradle-build-action@v2.

```
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: |
            ~/.gradle/caches
            ~/.gradle/wrapper
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-${{ hashFiles('**/*.gradle*', '**/gradle-wrapper.properties') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gradle-
```

```
    use: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
```

Comment: That's intentional: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#restrictions-for-accessing-a-cache